# Check Composer Install in My Local PC or Not

Tags: laravel-5, git-bash

I am new in laravel, so i need to know composer install my local pc.

> I also new in gitbash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$ composer --version
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to type in bash:

```
$ whereis composer
```

Comment: Can u help me @denis